# Load image file from ClassLoader in android

Tags: android, classloader, loadimage

I have a trouble with load image file in android project. I need to load from it because I have some private reasons.

here is my android project structure:
ProjectAA
----assets
----image
--------ic_next.png
----src
--------HomeActivity.java
----AndroidManifest.xml

I tried to load ic_next.png in HomeActivity.class with:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("image/ic_next.png");
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

but bm always return null. I also add "image" folder to java build path

I searched google but I can't find any solution. please help me.
Thanks

Comment: use "assets" folder for that, not "image"

Comment: why not use asset folder?

Comment: I want to export my project to jar file & using another application load it.

Comment: see this: https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/building-an-aar-library-in-android-studio/

Comment: @pskink : thank you for quick reply. My purpose is building this project to jar file. After that, my android application will read jar file from sd-card & playing some function in it. it like reading dynamic module. Is AAR working for me?

Comment: no: "aar" is a library module, not for "plugin" purposes

Answer (score 0):

Put image folder under src folder or include image folder as source folder in project settings.